# C# List Elements being overwritten when adding a new element

Tags: c#, parsing

So I am have an issue with adding a new object to a List using the .Add() call.

```
private static List<PointObject> _rawCoordinates = new List<PointObject>();    
private static void KMLParser(string fileLocation)
    {
        string coordinateString = "";

        XDocument document = XDocument.Load(fileLocation);
        XNamespace ns = "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2";

        var placemarks = document.Descendants(ns + "LineString")
                      .Select(p => new
                      {
                          Coord = p.Element(ns + "coordinates")
                      })
                      .ToList();

        foreach(var obj in placemarks)
        {
            coordinateString = Regex.Replace(obj.Coord.Value, @"\t|\n|\r| ", "");
            coordinateString = Regex.Replace(coordinateString, ",0", ",0\r");

            foreach (string substr in coordinateString.TrimEnd('\r').Split('\r'))
            {
                _rawCoordinates.Add(LineParser(substr));
            }
        }            
    }
private static PointObject LineParser(string Coordinates)
    {
        PointObject pt = new PointObject();
        int remainder;
        int index = 0; 

        foreach (string substr in Coordinates.TrimEnd('\n').Split(',', '\n'))
        {                
            remainder = index % 3;
            switch (remainder)
            {
                case 0:
                {
                    pt.SetLongitude(Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(substr), _round));
                    Debug.WriteLine("Longitude: {0}", pt.GetLongitude());
                    index++;
                    break;
                }
                case 1:
                {
                    pt.SetLatitude(Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(substr), _round));
                    Debug.WriteLine("Latitude: {0}", pt.GetLatitude());
                    index++;
                    break;
                }
                default:
                {
                    pt.SetBearing(0);
                    pt.SetDistance(0);
                    pt.SetIsStop(false);
                    pt.SetLayover(0);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return pt;
    }
```

So as you can see, I am add the returned PointObject from the LineParser Method,to the _rawCoordinates List, which is defined as a List.  I am initializing a new PointObject each time I call the LineParser method, and everything I found, that should have taken care of the issue.  However, each time I get a returned value from that method, it overwrites all elements in my _rawCoordinates List.  I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong here.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Adding my definition of PointObject

```
class PointObject
{
    public static double _bearing = 0;
    public static double _distance = 0;
    public static double _longitude = 0;
    public static double _latitude = 0;
    public static bool _isStop = false;
    public static int _layoverLength = 0;

    public PointObject()
    {
        _longitude = 0;
        _latitude = 0;
        _bearing = 0;
        _distance = 0;
        _isStop = false;
        _layoverLength = 0;
    }

    public PointObject(double lon, double lat, double dist, double bear, bool stop, int layover)
    {
        _longitude = lon;
        _latitude = lat;
        _distance = dist;
        _bearing = bear;
        _isStop = stop;
        _layoverLength = layover;
    }
```

}

So I am assuming you are going to want me to change those from public static to just public, right? If so, I can give it a try.

Comment: Can you add the definition of `PointObject` as well?  I suspect you are using static fields since everything else in your example is `static`.

Comment: Do you break into the code after the loop and check it? Does it have elements then? Is this class reinitialised anywhere else?

Comment: Try just remove static from all properties in PointObject..

Comment: D Stanley, That was the case, due to having the variables defined as a static, it was updating all of my elements.  After removing the Static from each of them, things are now working.  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in the comments above from D Standly and Johny Tee, but you shouldn't have properties that you want to have multiple copies of declared as static in your PointObject class.  Static means there is one copy of the field shared by all instances of the class (loose definition, see msdn for more details. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx)

So, change your PointObject definition to be something like:

```
class PointObject
{
    public double _bearing = 0;
    public double _distance = 0;
    public double _longitude = 0;
    public double _latitude = 0;
    public bool _isStop = false;
    public int _layoverLength = 0;

    public PointObject()
    {
        _longitude = 0;
        _latitude = 0;
        _bearing = 0;
        _distance = 0;
        _isStop = false;
        _layoverLength = 0;
    }

    public PointObject(double lon, double lat, double dist, double bear, bool stop, int layover)
    {
        _longitude = lon;
        _latitude = lat;
        _distance = dist;
        _bearing = bear;
        _isStop = stop;
        _layoverLength = layover;
    }
}
```

Comment: This certainly answers the question, though, might I suggest that you edit it to explain what should be done rather than what *shouldn't* be done?